# Is it possible to sell Rocket League Items?

Tags: steam, rocket-league

One of my Friends recently gave me some skins on Rocket league, but I don't play that often.

Is there a possible way to sell all Rocket league Items?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no officially supported way to sell Rocket League in-game items. However, Rocket League does have an in-game trading market that allows you to trade items with other players, although not for real money.

Note that for most games, any transactions outside the official ingame trading market are not officially supported by the devs and you may even risk getting your account banned when doing such transactions. This might not be the case for Rocket League because the game devs participate in some of the markets.

Comment: I'll stress that it can be a very bad idea to try and sell things in games that don't have an official channel to do so.  I'd expect to run into a lot of scammers; and if you get scammed I wouldn't expect anything to be done about it as the game does not support selling items.

Comment: @JMac There is actually a very large community around trusted traders and middlemen, with their own support for outside-game transactions. The game devs are aware of it and even participate on the subreddit. Not sure if this is true for other games.